# How to know if an event belongs to a date in html DOM of month timeline view

Tags: jquery, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I´m stuck trying to find out how to relate a Fullcalendar event (an anchor tag) to it´s date in Html DOM.

Looking at FullCalendar structure I notice that in `td.fc-time-area` there are two overlapping tables inside two divs: `.fc-content` and `.fc-bg`. The first one contains all rows of the calendar with events in anchor tag form. The second one has all columns to apply background color or other styles.

If I´m getting through every row of `.fc-content` to find events, how can I know if an event is in a concrete column (date)? Event anchor tag hasn´t any attribute to know the date it´s related.

[image: Time Area structure - FullCalendar]

Comment: why do you need to know, exactly? You're right, the HTML doesn't lend itself to detecting this - it's essentially a series of tables overlaid on each other to create an effect, rather than being a semantically meaningful structure. Also, the HTML changes entirely depending which view you use (timeline, agenda, list etc) so you'd potentially have to write code to deal with each one separately. If you explain to use what your actual end-goal is, maybe there's a better way to do it via the API (e.g. [fetching a list of events as an array](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/clientEvents), perhaps)

Comment: I´m trying to hide rows (resources) that hasn´t any event in a particular date. So my goal is that user can see only rows with content depending on what day have clicked in header.

Comment: Your idea could work... but I hoped there was a simpler solution via HTML.

Comment: I'm fairly sure if you look on fullCalendar's GitHub someone (possibly more than one person) has put in a feature request for something like that already. Maybe you should vote for it.